# Is there a way to validate a a BizTalk HIPAA message before the disassembler?

Tags: biztalk, x12, hipaa

We have a solution that receives HIPAA X12 files using the Multiple schema, then splits them and sends them on to the orchestration. Occasionally the client will send a file with a structural error somewhere in the middle, and the message will be suspended, but only after it's already send a few of the sub-documents on to the orchestration. This is annoying...

What I'd like to do is validate the entire message and suspend it before disassembling it into multiple messages... I know I could do this if I switched to the Single schema, or set Preserve Interchange, but then I have to deal with the splitting somewhere else.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Them->You tab of the Agreement under Local Host Settings.

The default option for Inbound batch processing option is to "suspend Transaction Sets (ST/SE) on error."

Change to "suspend Interchange on Error" and test to see if that satisfies your requirement.

That should work unless the Trading Partner sends files with multiple Interchanges.